# How do I implement custom Helpers in Code Igniter 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter

***Found the solution, refer to my answer.***

I've had a look through the [documentation](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/general/helpers.html) for CI4 and have played around with the Autoload file, but I don't fully understand how to load my custom helper in CI4.

My helper is very simple and is just called `customviews_helper.php` and it is located in `app/Helpers`. However, I have no clue of how to use it and load it.

The code I've created looks like this:

**customviews_helper.php**

```
class CustomViews {
    public static function generateMainView($name){
        $data = [
            'title' => $name,
            'view' => 'screens/'.$name,
        ];
        echo view('main', $data);
    }
}
```

**Home.php** (Controller)

```
class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        \CustomViews::generateMainView('Users');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried (the relevant code) and explain what happens. The documentation looks pretty straight forward so we need to know what you're actually doing.

Comment: Depending on the scope of the helper. if you want to see the helper everywhere in your application, then open autoload file, locate helpers array and add your helper name without suffix eg ( test_helper will be written as test). You can load a helper on specific controller, go to controller consrtuctor and simply add $this->load->helper('helper_name');

Comment: Worked it out, thank you for the prompt @MagnusEriksson - I've answered it below. My brain didn't read the documentation and see it previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation *does* tell you how to do it, just in a paragraph of text, with little context. To implement a custom helper in CI4 you have to do the following:

1. Create a file named "x_helper.php" in your app/Helpers folder
2. Define your class e.g. "CustomViews"
3. Create your functions, refer to the original post for my implementation
4. Wherever you want to use that helper, at the top of the function put `helper('x')` notice it is sans "_helper.php"
5. You may now use that helper as if it is a normal class e.g. `\CustomViews::generateMainView('Users');`

*x: name of the helper you wish to create, my example uses "customviews_helper"*